# Files uploaded in my orders are not being showed in backend or email confirmation

Tags: checkout, magento-1.8, configurable-product

I have a special product where my clients upload pictures so I can quote for the pictures they send me (product link: http://noivaimportada.com.br/vestido-de-noiva-sob-encomenda-seu-modelo-dos-sonhos-carregue-a-foto-ou-copie-o-link-1324.html)

It was working fine until I upgraded to Magento 1.8.

Now, they upload the pictures while ordering but we dont receive the files uploaded on the backend, neither on the order confirmation email like before. They just dont load at all.

Any help in where and how I could fix this problem?

Thank you so much for the help.